# Not Working - AlamoFire, Swift 4.2 to Upload Image to Raspberry Pi Server

Tags: swift, alamofire, raspberry-pi3

I want to send an image from iOS (Swift 4.2) to my Raspberry Pi Server (192.168.0.102/TestFiles). Swift/Alamofire code is below.

```
func uploadImage(){

    var imageToUpload:UIImage = UIImage()
    //let picture = showPicture.image

     imageToUpload = showPicture.image!

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!, withName: "Prescription", fileName: "Profile_Image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:"http://192.168.0.102/TestFiles")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            print(result)

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print(progress)
            })

            upload.responseString { response in
                //print response.result
                print(response);
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError);
        }
    }
}
```

On my Pi, I have a simple apache server setup. I'm relatively new to programming so I don't have any code (php or otherwise) running on it. I am trying to just get static file uploads working first (if that's even possible).

When I run the Swift code, the image doesn't show up in my Pi folder. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the response I get in my debugger:

```
2018-11-22 01:38:09.663963-0600 selectpicture[64265:1374728] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-11-22 01:38:12.399335-0600 selectpicture[64265:1375005] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
success(request: 2018-11-22 01:38:13.375848-0600 selectpicture[64265:1374728] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    atyp = http;
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = http;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "192.168.0.102";
    srvr = "192.168.0.102";
    sync = syna;
}
$ curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0" \
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=alamofire.boundary.5afc2d458fda0c8d" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
    -H "User-Agent: selectpicture/1.0 (com.tapanpatel.selectpicture; build:1; iOS 12.1.0) Alamofire/4.7.3" \
    "http://192.168.0.102/TestFiles", streamingFromDisk: false, streamFileURL: nil)
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0106 / Completed: 65536 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0106 / Completed: 65536 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0158 / Completed: 98304 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0264 / Completed: 163840 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0317 / Completed: 196608 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0369 / Completed: 229376 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0369 / Completed: 229376 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0422 / Completed: 262144 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0475 / Completed: 294912 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0528 / Completed: 327680 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0580 / Completed: 360448 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0633 / Completed: 393216 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0686 / Completed: 425984 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0739 / Completed: 458752 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0791 / Completed: 491520 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0844 / Completed: 524288 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0897 / Completed: 557056 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0950 / Completed: 589824 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1003 / Completed: 622592 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1055 / Completed: 655360 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1108 / Completed: 688128 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1161 / Completed: 720896 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1214 / Completed: 753664 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1266 / Completed: 786432 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1319 / Completed: 819200 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1372 / Completed: 851968 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1425 / Completed: 884736 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1530 / Completed: 950272 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1530 / Completed: 950272 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1583 / Completed: 983040 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1636 / Completed: 1015808 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1688 / Completed: 1048576 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1741 / Completed: 1081344 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1794 / Completed: 1114112 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1847 / Completed: 1146880 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1900 / Completed: 1179648 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.1952 / Completed: 1212416 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2058 / Completed: 1277952 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2111 / Completed: 1310720 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2111 / Completed: 1310720 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2163 / Completed: 1343488 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2216 / Completed: 1376256 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2269 / Completed: 1409024 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2322 / Completed: 1441792 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2374 / Completed: 1474560 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2427 / Completed: 1507328 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2480 / Completed: 1540096 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2533 / Completed: 1572864 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2585 / Completed: 1605632 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2638 / Completed: 1638400 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2744 / Completed: 1703936 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2797 / Completed: 1736704 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2849 / Completed: 1769472 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2849 / Completed: 1769472 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2902 / Completed: 1802240 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.2955 / Completed: 1835008 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3008 / Completed: 1867776 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3060 / Completed: 1900544 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3113 / Completed: 1933312 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3166 / Completed: 1966080 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3271 / Completed: 2031616 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3324 / Completed: 2064384 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3324 / Completed: 2064384 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3377 / Completed: 2097152 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3430 / Completed: 2129920 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3535 / Completed: 2195456 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3535 / Completed: 2195456 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3588 / Completed: 2228224 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3641 / Completed: 2260992 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3694 / Completed: 2293760 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3746 / Completed: 2326528 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3799 / Completed: 2359296 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3852 / Completed: 2392064 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.3905 / Completed: 2424832 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4010 / Completed: 2490368 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4010 / Completed: 2490368 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4063 / Completed: 2523136 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4116 / Completed: 2555904 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4168 / Completed: 2588672 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4274 / Completed: 2654208 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4274 / Completed: 2654208 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4327 / Completed: 2686976 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4379 / Completed: 2719744 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4485 / Completed: 2785280 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4485 / Completed: 2785280 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4538 / Completed: 2818048 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4591 / Completed: 2850816 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4643 / Completed: 2883584 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4696 / Completed: 2916352 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4749 / Completed: 2949120 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4802 / Completed: 3014656 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4854 / Completed: 3014656 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4907 / Completed: 3047424 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.4960 / Completed: 3080192 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5013 / Completed: 3112960 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5065 / Completed: 3145728 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5118 / Completed: 3178496 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5224 / Completed: 3244032 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5276 / Completed: 3276800 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5329 / Completed: 3309568 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5329 / Completed: 3309568 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5382 / Completed: 3342336 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5435 / Completed: 3375104 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5488 / Completed: 3407872 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5540 / Completed: 3440640 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5593 / Completed: 3473408 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5646 / Completed: 3506176 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5699 / Completed: 3538944 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5751 / Completed: 3571712 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5804 / Completed: 3604480 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5857 / Completed: 3637248 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5910 / Completed: 3670016 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5962 / Completed: 3702784 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6015 / Completed: 3735552 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6068 / Completed: 3768320 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6121 / Completed: 3801088 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6173 / Completed: 3833856 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6226 / Completed: 3866624 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6279 / Completed: 3899392 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6332 / Completed: 3932160 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6385 / Completed: 3964928 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6437 / Completed: 3997696 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6543 / Completed: 4063232 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6596 / Completed: 4096000 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6596 / Completed: 4096000 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6648 / Completed: 4128768 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6701 / Completed: 4161536 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6754 / Completed: 4194304 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6807 / Completed: 4227072 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6859 / Completed: 4259840 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6912 / Completed: 4292608 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.6965 / Completed: 4325376 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7018 / Completed: 4358144 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7070 / Completed: 4390912 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7123 / Completed: 4423680 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7176 / Completed: 4456448 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7229 / Completed: 4489216 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7282 / Completed: 4521984 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7334 / Completed: 4554752 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7440 / Completed: 4620288 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7493 / Completed: 4653056 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7545 / Completed: 4685824 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7651 / Completed: 4751360 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7704 / Completed: 4784128 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7704 / Completed: 4784128 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7704 / Completed: 4784128 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7756 / Completed: 4816896 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7809 / Completed: 4849664 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7862 / Completed: 4882432 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7915 / Completed: 4915200 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.7967 / Completed: 4947968 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8020 / Completed: 4980736 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8073 / Completed: 5013504 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8126 / Completed: 5046272 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8179 / Completed: 5079040 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8284 / Completed: 5144576 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8337 / Completed: 5177344 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8390 / Completed: 5210112 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8442 / Completed: 5242880 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8442 / Completed: 5242880 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8495 / Completed: 5275648 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8548 / Completed: 5308416 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8601 / Completed: 5341184 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8653 / Completed: 5373952 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8706 / Completed: 5406720 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8759 / Completed: 5439488 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8812 / Completed: 5472256 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8864 / Completed: 5505024 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8917 / Completed: 5537792 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.8970 / Completed: 5570560 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9023 / Completed: 5603328 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9076 / Completed: 5636096 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9128 / Completed: 5668864 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9181 / Completed: 5701632 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9234 / Completed: 5734400 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9287 / Completed: 5767168 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9339 / Completed: 5799936 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9392 / Completed: 5832704 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9445 / Completed: 5865472 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9498 / Completed: 5898240 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9603 / Completed: 5963776 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9656 / Completed: 5996544 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9709 / Completed: 6029312 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9762 / Completed: 6062080 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9814 / Completed: 6094848 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9867 / Completed: 6127616 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9920 / Completed: 6160384 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.9973 / Completed: 6193152 of 6210192  
<NSProgress: 0x600000c75ae0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 6210192 of 6210192  
SUCCESS: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /TestFiles</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /TestFiles</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="UploadHere/">UploadHere/</a></td><td align="right">2018-11-22 00:53  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.0.102 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to upload your image to the web page url that allows uploading images from?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean but I've given the TestFiles folder (/var/www/html/TestFiles) permissions - sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/TestFiles.